# Gap between array columns

Tags: tcolorbox, arrays

I am using an array inside a tcolorbox, but I am getting this unwanted gap between the columns of the array. How do I make this array perfectly fit into the parent tcolorbox and remove the gap between columns?

[image: Screenshot]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{darkgrey}{HTML}{E2E1E6}

%problembox environment
\newenvironment{problembox}
{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        colframe=white,
        colback=darkgrey,
        boxrule=0pt,
        fontupper=\sffamily,
        arc=0pt,
        top=0pt,
        bottom=0pt,
        left=0pt,
        right=0pt,
        boxsep=0pt,
        ]
        \small
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% Remove column spacing
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.33\textwidth}
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.33\textwidth}
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.33\textwidth}@{}}
            \rowcolor{blue!10}
            \textbf{Problem Name} & \textbf{Source} & \textbf{Difficulty} \\
        }{%
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Algorithms}
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{problembox}
        P1 & S1 & Easy \\
        P2 & S2 & Difficult \\
        P3 & S3 & Normal \\
        P4 & S4 & Normal \\
        P5 & S5 & Hard \\
    \end{problembox}
    
    \lipsum[2]
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually want to put your tabular inside an environment of `tcolorbox`, you may try `nicematrix`. That package provides an environment `{NiceTabular*}` similar to the classical `{tabular}` but which uses PGF/Tikz to color the rows (that environment `{NiceTabular*}` should be used here with the key `colortbl-like`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{array}
% \usepackage{colortbl} % not loaded 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\definecolor{darkgrey}{HTML}{E2E1E6}

%problembox environment
\newenvironment{problembox}
{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        colframe=white,
        colback=darkgrey,
        boxrule=0pt,
        fontupper=\sffamily,
        arc=0pt,
        top=0pt,
        bottom=0pt,
        left=0pt,
        right=0pt,
        boxsep=0pt,
        ]
        \small
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% Remove column spacing
        \begin{NiceTabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.33\textwidth}
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.33\textwidth}
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.33\textwidth}@{}}[colortbl-like]
            \rowcolor{blue!10}
            \textbf{Problem Name} & \textbf{Source} & \textbf{Difficulty} \\
        }{%
        \end{NiceTabular*}
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Algorithms}
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{problembox}
        P1 & S1 & Easy \\
        P2 & S2 & Difficult \\
        P3 & S3 & Normal \\
        P4 & S4 & Normal \\
        P5 & S5 & Hard \\
    \end{problembox}
    
    \lipsum[2]
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, a solution with a `tcbraster` (or `tcbitemize`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{darkgrey}{HTML}{E2E1E6}

%problembox environment
\newenvironment{problembox}
{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tcbitemize}[
        colframe=white,
        colback=darkgrey,
        fontupper=\small\sffamily,
        sharp corners,
        raster columns=3,
        raster column skip=0pt,
        raster row skip=0pt,
        raster equal height=rows,
        raster row 1/.style={colback=black!30},
        halign=center,
        size=small,
        boxrule=0pt,
        ]}
{    \end{tcbitemize}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Algorithms}
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{problembox}
        \tcbitem Problem Name
        \tcbitem Source
        \tcbitem Difficulty
        \tcbitem P1
        \tcbitem S1
        \tcbitem Easy
        \tcbitem P2
        \tcbitem S3
        \tcbitem Difficult
        \tcbitem P3
        \tcbitem S3
        \tcbitem Normal
    \end{problembox}
    
    \lipsum[2]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

(I rewrote this answer after realizing that my initial answer was focused on a different type of "gap" than what the OP cared about.)

> How do I make this array perfectly fit into the parent tcolorbox and remove the gap between columns?

Note that in

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.33\textwidth}
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.33\textwidth}
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.33\textwidth}@{}}
```

the combined width of the three columns is `0.99\textwidth`, *not* `1.00\textwidth`. Conversely, the width of both inter-column gaps is `0.005\textwidth`, not `0pt`. To fix this issue, just replace the code snippet shown above with

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.333\textwidth}
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.333\textwidth}
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.334\textwidth}@{}}
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{darkgrey}{HTML}{E2E1E6}

%problembox environment
\newenvironment{problembox}
{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        colframe=white,
        colback=darkgrey,
        boxrule=0pt,
        fontupper=\sffamily,
        arc=0pt,
        top=0pt,
        bottom=0pt,
        left=0pt,
        right=0pt,
        boxsep=0pt,
        ]
        \small
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% no inter-column whitespace padding
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.333\textwidth}
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.333\textwidth}
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.334\textwidth} @{}}
            \rowcolor{blue!10}
            \textbf{Problem Name} & \textbf{Source} & \textbf{Difficulty} \\
        }{%
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Algorithms}
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{problembox}
        P1 & S1 & Easy \\
        P2 & S2 & Difficult \\
        P3 & S3 & Normal \\
        P4 & S4 & Normal \\
        P5 & S5 & Hard \\
    \end{problembox}
    
    \lipsum[2]
    
\end{document}
```